# Struggling to fix error: 'Failed to render and update auto layout status for VC: The Agent Crashed' Xcode 10.2

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, ios-autolayout

I am really struggling to identify what is causing these issues and how to fix them. I have read through many threads and articles but can't seem to pin-point the root cause.

It appears that since I upgraded Xcode to the latest version 10.2 these issues started to appear.

So far I have , quit then restarted Xcode, clean-built the project, deleted my `Derived Data` folder, ran Editor/Refresh All Views and with the help of this [article](https://blog.kaltoun.cz/debugging-ibdesignable/) I was able to locate the `IBDesignablesAgent` crash files using the Console app but nothing seems to work and the content of these files (see screenshot below) are so foreign to me that I can't work out what is causing it.

Your assistance is much appreciated please/

Xcode errors:

[image]

`IBDesignablesAgent` crash files:

[image]

Comment: I was plagued with these assertions too whenever I viewed my project in Interface Builder. In the end I just removed all `@IBDesignable` from the affected viewController's source file. I had to also remove it from the custom view's source files that were contained in the viewController to make the assertion go away. I know this isn't an answer and I'd much rather solve/fix this but like you I dug down until I just got lost and decided that I can live without a pretty VC in IB.

Comment: Thanks for your input, stupid question, what do you mean when you say you removed all the ‘IBDesignable’, and how did you build your view controller after that, programmatically? Also, the app compiled and runs as per normal, cam this be ignored? Would it be an issue if it is submitted for approval to the App Store with these messages?

Comment: I'd added IBDesignable to my swift classes so that changes I made in the inspectors were reflected in Interface Builder (e.g. https://medium.com/@nimjea/ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-in-swift-c12ea557b82b) My VC had custom views in it that I'd also added @IBDesignable to so I had to remove those too in order to lose the error message. The error might be due to these embedded views but I don't know for certain. I still build my VC in Interface Builder but currently without the custom effects being visible. I don't know if it would be a problem submitting to Apple as I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: Here is the interesting thing, I am not using `@IBDesignables` anywhere in my code :(

Comment: Ah... that's strange. Sorry to have wasted your time. If you do find a solution then please post it here as it could well help me sort my (related) problem if I ever get time to look more deeply into it.

Comment: Sure no problems.

Comment: @Magnas so as it turns out I did have a class with an `@IBDesignable` which I didnt use, I've removed it and the errors since to have disappeared. Your suggestions did help after all :)